# pandas read_csv raises IncompleteRead on a dataset I could download before with no issues

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

All of a sudden these two lines are no longer working, returning a `IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(26300352 bytes read, 3212014 more expected)`

```py
df_commuter = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/uber-web/kepler.gl-data/raw/master/ukcommute/data.csv")
df_commuter.head()
```

I tried with a range of python version, machines and pandas version, to no avail.
This was working fine in about 10 seconds, now for some reasons it does no longer work.

Anyone has a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, that is as simple as downloading the data in local before reading it to the dataframe.

Though any insight about how to fix it via pandas (a timeout flag I am missing somewhere that came out out of the blue, or a connection timer to github...) is very welcome.

```py
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keplergl/kepler.gl-data/master/ukcommute/data.csv -o ./z_commuters_data.csv

df_commuter = pd.read_csv("./z_commuters_data.csv")
```